# Finding the efficiency of a search? algorithm. C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

I've been told to find the efficiency of this code, and we've been ~1 hour (me and my partner) trying to find out what this code really does.

We supposed this is a search algorithm, but we can't really find a way to make it work w/o getting into an infinite loop:

```
int busq(int *v, int x, int b, int a){
    int m1, m2;
    int result;
    m1 = (b+a) / 3;
    m2 = 2*m1;

    if (v[m1] == x)
         result = m1;
    else
        if (v[m2] == x)
            result = m2;
        else
            if (x<v[m1])
                result = busq(v, x, b, m1-1);
            else
                if (x>v[m2])
                    result = busq(v, x, m2+1, a);
                else
                    result = busq(v, x, m1+1, m2-1);
    return result;
}
```

That's all we are given, no value for the parameters a,b or x, not the size of *v (the vector) or the content of the vector.

It's supposed to be possible to solve it like this.

If anything we want to know what this code does, but if you can tell us the efficiency, it will be appreciated as well. (We use the O() notation E.J.: O(1), O(n^2)...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically [ternary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search).  `v` has to be a sorted array, `x` is the value searched for and `b` ist the begin of the range and `a` is the end (exclusive).

The function attempts to divide the range into three about equal partitions at `m1`, `m2` (which are both calculated wrong and only work if you search for the first element) and checks whether x lies on the bounds. If not, it recurses with the partition x has to lie in.

The code can be fixed with

```
m1=b+(a-b)/3;
m2=b+(a-b)*2/3;
```

Then, the efficiency should be O(log n)

Comment: Why you think it would work on b=0? We tried as follows: v[100] each position as: 0,1...99. Then a=99 and b=0. It makes an infinite loop while searching for 11.

Comment: It works if always b=0 i.e. you are searching for the first element in the array. Otherwise ... well fix the code with `m1=b+(a-b)/3` and `m2=b+(a-b)*2/3`.

Comment: How you made the conclusion that it is O(log n)?

Comment: see linked wikipedia artikel

Comment: Space complexity is technically O(log n) too, but since most compilers apply tail call optimization here, it's O(1) in practice.

Comment: It is recursive, but uses tail recursion, so it could be implemented in a loop (some compilers unwind tail recursion into a loop).  Using recursion costs memory but expresses a simpler algorithm.

Comment: The difference between binary and ternary (splitting in 2 or in 3) doesn't change O() complexity, but can improve performance (50%).  The important thing to the algorithmic complexity is the splitting the search space in 1/2 (well, 1/3) each step.  That is what makes it log (base2) (n).

Comment: @ChuckCottrill: Yes, it is faster, but this has to do with [caches](http://www.pvk.ca/Blog/2012/07/30/binary-search-is-a-pathological-case-for-caches/) not splitting the search space in 1/3.